# get_the_terms_list output last child only

Tags: categories, archives

I'm using `get_the_term_list` on an archive page which currently outputs all categories that a post is in with links.

My question: Is it possible to only display the last child category, not any parents or grandparents?

Thios is what I have that outputs all:

```
<?php if( get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'event-category') ){ 
    echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(),'event-category', '', ', ', '' ); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It turns out that this doesn’t list the parent categories anyway!